# PHP script execution exceeding memory limit, even though limit is higher

Tags: php

I have a PHP script on a Linux server that I am executing via command line like so: `php script.php` (note that it's not being executed as part of a web request).

The `memory_limit` in the server's "php.ini" file is set to "512M", and I have verified this as follows:

```
# echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" | php | grep memory_limit
memory_limit => 512M => 512M
```

Now, the issue is that when I execute the script in question via `php script.php`, eventually I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 600283 bytes) in ...

268435456 bytes ~= 268mb, which is definitely lower than 512mb

What could be happening here? Is it possible there is another system-level setting I am missing? Or are php processes intrinsically limited to ~ 268mb?

Comment: did your restart apache? did you check if there's a memory_limit somewhere else that's overriding the .ini copy? checking at the command line is pointless, since that generally uses a DIFFERENT .ini file set than sapi (aka web-based). you need to check `php_info()` within the script that you're having the problem in.

Comment: Dump a [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.memory-get-usage.php) on the line before the script crashes

Comment: Also, Suhosin extension can put its own cap on memory limit. Did you check that?

Comment: Have you tried passing memory limit dirrectly into command? `php -d memory_limit=512M script.php`

Comment: @MarcB like I mentioned in the question, I'm executing the script via the command-line, not apache (or any other web server).

Comment: Did the dump of memory_get_usage returned an other value than the one written in the fatal error ? Have you tried it with both real_usage to true and false ?

Comment: @elsurudo Can you try to in your script `echo ini_get("memory_limit"); die();` ? please

Comment: @Answers_Seeker right before failure: Mem: 325567640, Real mem: 335806464 It's higher than the failure suggests, but still lower than the (supposed) limit. Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: @zilongqiu Answer is "512M", so it is indeed getting set properly.

Comment: This might sound dumb but: Is the memory limit applied per script or for the whole server ? if it's for the whole server, isn't there an other script running using the left memory ?

Comment: @Answers_Seeker According to http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit it's per-script

Comment: Ok, does a PHP version of John Skeet exists on stackoverflow ? :D Only this could help us

Answer (score -1):

You could use php -i and grep the output to check that you've updated the correct php.ini,

php -i | grep php.ini

Comment: Well, if console says memory_limit => 512M => 512M then everyting is OK with the php.ini

Answer (score -6):

Most likely php.ini settings didn't take effect. Restart the server again, and run script with phpinfo() to make sure your changes are in place.